django qs annotated field duplicate sql
I have this query in django
qs_match_annotation = "some sub query"
qs = qs.annotate(match=qs_match_annotation)
qs = qs.filter(match__gt=0)
qs = qs.order_by("-match")


the sql generated for the qs_match_annotation is written again in the order_by instead of just generating
ORDER BY match DESC

it writes the whole subquery again
how to fix such thing?

Do you need it in the SELECT.

@willeM_ Van Onsem
now following


how to fix such thing?

You don't. It is one of the inefficiencies of the Django ORM that will (probably) eventually get fixed. As far as I know it is also not standard SQL that you can refer to a column in the SELECT query: some dialects (might) not allow this, and yes, I found that stupid as well.
But it typically has only a very small impact on performance, because typically most effort is wasted in fetching the data.
If you don't need match in the SELECT query, you can however use an .alias(…) [Django-doc]:
qs = qs.alias(match=qs_match_annotation).filter(match__gt=0).order_by('-match')
Then at least it is not duplicated in the SELECT clause.

After searching this is actually a SQL behavior, you can't use aliases in where statement
doesn't mean it will be evaluated more than one time (depending on the database optimization engine)

@mohamednaser: not per se, strictly speaking that is possible, but not all databases allow this.

So, apparently this is a sql problem not django
you can't have an alias in the were statement.
probably the alias won't be evaluated in the where part of the query execution.
So, the db can't use a column it doesn't have and as a result they forbid it
does it mean the alias sql will be evaluated more than once?
No, depending on the database optimization engine but most probably no, the only insufficient here is writing the same sql more than once but has no effect on the performance
also, if you don't care about the match value returned
use qs.alias() to prevent it from being written there as well
